# Circumventing Retrofit's "baseUrl must end in /"

Tags: retrofit2

I use *Retrofit 2.3.0* to interact with OAI-PMH endpoints.

I now happen to interact with an endpoint which is picky about whether its base URL ends with a slash or not:

Without slash:

http://www.relacionesinternacionales.info/ojs/oai.html?verb=Identify works as intended.

With slash:

http://www.relacionesinternacionales.info/ojs/oai.html/?verb=Identify causes a redirect to a 404 page.

Now the problem is that Retrofit 2.3.0 demands base URLs to end with a slash.

Providing the Retrofit builder with the no-ending-slash base URL makes Retrofit complain.

Providing the Retrofit builder with the ending-with-a-slash base URL causes Retrofit to build an incorrect URL, causing the 404 error.

How can I circumvent this limitation?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I use *Java Reflection* to manipulate the `Retrofit` object's `baseUrl` field.

First, the code checks if the provided `baseUrl` ends with a slash. If so, nothing particular has to happen.

In case the provided `baseUrl` does not end with a slash, first the `retrofit` object is created with a trailing slash to `baseUrl`, then later this baseUrl object is replaced with the original non-slash-ending baseUrl:

```
String baseUrl = "..."; // can end with slash or not

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl( baseUrl.endsWith("/") ? baseUrl : baseUrl + "/" )
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

// workaround for https://stackoverflow.com/q/47331753/923560
if ( ! baseUrl.endsWith("/") ) {
    try {
        Field baseUrlField = retrofit.getClass().getDeclaredField("baseUrl");
        baseUrlField.setAccessible(true);
        HttpUrl newHttpUrl = HttpUrl.parse(baseUrl);
        baseUrlField.set(retrofit, newHttpUrl);
        baseUrlField.setAccessible(false);
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        LOG.error("Exception while manipulating baseUrl=" + baseUrl + " to not end with a slash", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

service = retrofit.create(OaiPmhService.class);
// ...
```